# Uniformly Continuous Function and Limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, uniform-continuity

### **Question:** Given that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$, show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{1+x^2} = 0$.

*What I know:*

Uniform continuity: For every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists\,\delta > 0$ such that for all $x,y \in [0,\infty)$, if $|x-y| < \delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$.

*Want to show:*

$|\frac{f(x)}{1+x^2}| < \epsilon$ as $x \to \infty$.

*Attempt #1:* I attempted to show that $f$ is Lipschitz but doesn't seem to be the case.

*Attempt #2:* Tried to re-write $|x-y| < \delta$ as $|x| - |y| < \delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$ as $|f(x)| - |f(y)| < \epsilon$ to manipulate the expression but to no avail.

Also thought of trying to show that $f(x)$ "moves slower" than $1+x^2$ or $x^2$ in the limit but not sure how to put it exactly.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, then for $\varepsilon=1$, there exists a $\delta>0$, such that
$$
|x-y|<\delta \quad\Longrightarrow\quad |f(x)-f(y)|<1.
$$
Pick $h$, with $0<h<\delta$.
So, for every $x>0$, set $n=\big[\frac{x}{h}\big]$. Then
$$
|f(x)-f(0)|\le |f(0)-f(h)|+|f(h)-f(2h)|+\cdots+\\|f\big((n-1)h\big)-f(nh)|+|f(nh)-f(x)| < n+1<\frac{x}{h}+1,
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{|f(x)|}{1+x^2}< \frac{|f(0)|+\frac{x}{h}+1}{x^2+1}\to 0
$$
as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and nice answer! Just a quick confirmation: Does $[\frac{x}{h}]$ means the floor function? And in the last line, would it be more accurate to use $<$ instead of $\leq$, since $|f(x)| < |f(0)| + \frac{x}{h} + 1$?

Comment: Yes and yes in both cases.